# Detect touch on UIButton below UIScrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, scrollview

I am working on an app, and wanted to know if the following would be possible. I have a UIScrollView on top of an existing UIView which has UIButtons. The UIScrollView stops the touches from reaching the UIButtons below it.

Can I detect user touches on the UIButtons that is below the UIScrollView? The UIScrollView has clear backgroundColor so the user can still see everything under it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can the system know if a touch is intended to tap the buttons or scroll the scroll view? For buttons _within_ the scroll view (subviews), there is the `delaysContentTouches` property; but for controls _outside_ the scroll view I don't think it makes sense...

Comment: i was thinking that maybe the scrollview can ignore touches because it needs swipes in order to be scrolled, if you tap a scroll view nothing happens

Comment: A swipe begins with a tap.

Comment: No you cannot, unless it is hidden or alpha is invisible.

Comment: if it is hidden or if i set alpha to 0 will i still be able to scroll

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Swift coder, i could link you all the methods , but I guess you can handle it yourself, unless you can't let me know I will update the answer. However, the solution for you:

First you need to add a UITapGestureRecognizer with **a single tap** to your UIScrollView.

Detect the tap CGPoint (user touchpoint) inside your tapGesture method:
(Objective-c)

```
CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scrollView];
```

Then do a check if the touchPoint is inside the view below it with [CGRectContainsPoint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cggeometry#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint)

```
bool CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, CGPoint point);
```

If so, just fire the action, otherwise ignore it. :)

Comment: @user6520705 NP, please mark as answered if it solves your problem (which it should) :)